# size of UIView based on drawRect

Tags: ios, uiview, overlay, drawrect, polygons

so here's the scenario, I would like to add a UIView in the shape of a irregular polygon on top of another UIView. I draw the irregular polygon using the UIView's drawRect method.

I would like to know how to make the frame of the UIView that of the irregular polygon's?

Obiviously i can't use initWithFrame as that would give it a rectangular frame.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

A UIView's frame *is* a rectangle. From the [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) page:

> **frame**
>
> The frame rectangle, which describes the view’s location and
>   size in its superview’s coordinate system.
>
> @property(nonatomic) CGRect frame

So, you're never going to make the view's `frame` anything other than a `CGRect`. What you *can* do, however, is to just use the rectangle as the enclosing rectangle for your polygon. Draw the polygon so that it just fits inside the rectangle, and leave the area outside the polygon transparent.

Comment: Yes but that way there could be overlapping polygons with each other since the view's are bigger than they need to be and would overlap with each other. What im trying to do is implement viewForAnnotation for maps, and i need to give each annotation a custom view in the shape of a polygon, and when the polygon is tapped, a call out appears, not sure what will happen if the polygons overlap with each other though. Is there any other way?

Comment: Override `-pointInside:withEvent:` in your view, and return YES only if the point is in your polygon.